# Return a list of column headers across a row when cells have text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get a list of column headers for each cell that contains a text value.

Eg.

```
    A--------------B-------------C-------------BC (desired output)  
1   Header1        Header2       Header3              
2   M                            T             Header1, Header3  
3   T              MT                          Header1, Header2  
4                  TMW                         Header2
```

In the final product I want to use two final columns with formulas listing headers from cells with values across 9 columns and a second with the other 40 odd columns.

I have the vague notion that I might need to use `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `IF` functions - but as a novice have no idea how to string them together coherently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will make use of VBA's [`Join` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098%28v=office.14%29.aspx). VBA functions aren't directly available in Excel, so I wrap `Join` in a user-defined function that exposes the same functionality:

```
Function JoinXL(arr As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = " ")
    JoinXL = Join(arr, delimiter)
End Function
```

The formula in D2 is:

```
=JoinXL(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:C2)),$A$1:$C$1&", ",""),"")
```

entered as an [array formula](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel%20array%20formula) (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>). It is then copied down.

[image]

Explanation:

- `NOT(ISBLANK(A2:C2))` detects which cells have text in them; returns this array for row 2: `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}`
- `IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:C2)),$A$1:$C$1&", ","")` converts those boolean values to row 1 contents followed by a comma delimiter; returns the array `{"Header A, ","","Header C, "}`.
- `JoinXL` joins the contents of that array into a single string.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help- took me 30 mins but I finally figured out how to use this vba approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use worksheet functions, and not VBA, I suggest returning each column header in a separate cell.  You can do this by entering a formula such as:

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
BC: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1,1,SMALL((LEN($A2:$C2)>0)*COLUMN($A2:$C2),COUNTBLANK($A2:$C2)+COLUMNS($A:A))),"")
```

Adjust the range references A:C to reflect the columns actually used for your data.  Be sure to use the same mixed address format as in above.  Do NOT change the $A:A reference, however.

Then fill right until you get blanks; and fill down as far as required.

You can reverse the logic to get a list of the "other" headers.

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.

If you really need to have the results as comma-separated values in two different columns, I would suggest the following User Defined Function.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), **alt-F11** opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=Headers($A2:$BA2,$A$1:$BA$1,True)
```

or, to get the headers that do NOT contain text:

```
=Headers($A2:$BA2,$A$1:$BA$1,FALSE)
```

in some cell.

=====================================================

```
Option Explicit
Function Headers(rData As Range, rHeaders As Range, Optional bTextPresent As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim colHeaders As Collection
    Dim vData, vHeaders
    Const sDelimiter As String = ", "
    Dim sRes() As String
    Dim I As Long
vData = rData
vHeaders = rHeaders
Set colHeaders = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vData, 2)
    If (Len(vData(1, I)) > 0) = bTextPresent Then colHeaders.Add vHeaders(1, I)
Next I

ReDim sRes(1 To colHeaders.Count)
For I = 1 To colHeaders.Count
    sRes(I) = colHeaders(I)
Next I

Headers = Join(sRes, sDelimiter)
End Function
```

==========================================

You should probably add some logic to the routine to ensure your range arguments are a single row, and that the two arguments are of the same size.